# How can I open every link within my forum after filtering all of the available href tags?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Can it be possible to add a click on link event or a new tab for all possible links so that I can scrape my forum I had to filter the forum by using the URL as a filter by grabbing all links that contain viewthread but when I try to get it to click on it just ends with no errors can someone explain it to me as I am very new to web scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   options = Options()
   options.add_argument("start-maximized")

   webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
   url = "https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/viewforum/2989694/m/11178354/page/1"
   driver.get(url)
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

   elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='structure small-cells']//a[@href]")

   for elem in elems:
       if "viewthread" in elem.get_attribute('href'):
          print(elem.get_attribute("href"))

   links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='structure small-cells']//a[@href]")

   for link in links:
       if "veiwthread" in link.get_attribute("href"):
           wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
           wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='structure small-cells']//a[@href]']")))
           print(driver.page_source)

           link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@href]")
           link.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import window
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/viewforum/2989694/m/11178354/page/1")
elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='structure small-cells']//a[@href]")
links = []

for ele in elems:
    if "viewthread" in ele.get_attribute("href"):
        links.append(ele.get_attribute("href"))

for link in links:
    driver.switch_to.new_window(window.WindowTypes.TAB)
    driver.get(link)
```

Notice that elems is a list that contains selenium's WebElements and what we need is the href of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think enjin.com is using some mechanisms that are blocking Selenium from scraping files ChromeDriver directly closes the browser, but using Firefox's Gecko Driver would show that Selenium is stuck at [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8jy.png), making Selenium failing to select the elements in the latter part of your code. You might want to check on how to [conceal Selenium](https://staffordwilliams.com/blog/2020/07/08/browser-fingerprinting-concealing-selenium/).

Comment: No, to avoid getting the browser closed you just need to add this option:  `options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)`